# Email Not sending From Live Server Website But Working on Local server

Tags: php, email

In my website, there is form submission, it will send email to those user, but in my local server the code is working perfectly

```
    <?php

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"];

require "vendor/autoload.php";

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

// $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

$mail->Host = "back2naturekw.com";
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'None';
$mail->Port = 587;

$mail->Username = "info@back2naturekw.com";
$mail->Password = "***hidden****";

$mail->setFrom('info@back2naturekw.com', 'Back To Nature');
$mail->addAddress($email, $name);

$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $message;

$mail->send();

header("Location: send.php");
```

but when i added this code in my go daddy hosting there is showing error : connection refuse,
in here i used email is cpanel email,

Error Message is
2023-07-02 13:51:53 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111)
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to server

Fatal error: Uncaught PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Failed to connect to server in /srv/disk5/4339946/www/testersaf.atwebpages.com/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php:2233 Stack trace: #0 /srv/disk5/4339946/www/testersaf.atwebpages.com/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(2019): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpConnect(Array) #1 /srv/disk5/4339946/www/testersaf.atwebpages.com/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1678): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->smtpSend('Date: Sun, 2 Ju...', 'final\r\n') #2 /srv/disk5/4339946/www/testersaf.atwebpages.com/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php(1516): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->postSend() #3 /srv/disk5/4339946/www/testersaf.atwebpages.com/send-email.php(33): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send() #4 {main} thrown in /srv/disk5/4339946/www/testersaf.atwebpages.com/vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php on line 2233

i think may godaddy dns records need to add something, i don't know is there anything to add for the email. but sending email and also working perfectly on local server. only issue with live server

please anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

Godaddy [restrict SMTP connections to their own server](https://community.godaddy.com/s/question/0D53t00006Vm1nsCAB/could-not-connect-to-smtp-host) on most hosting plans.

This is a deliberate limitation by your service provider.

Comment: I think DNS records need to add something, so it will work??

Comment: @MuhammadSafnad — No. DNS is resolving the host name. The connection is blocked by Godaddy’s firewall.